# Absolute values and Inequalities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$|3x - |x+1||  ≥ 2 $$

And

$$|\frac{3}{5}x - 2| < 4 < \frac{x^2 + 6x - 4 }{ x + 1}$$

I hope that makes sense. Is my first time asking a Question.
To questions. Need to find x in both of them. Can somebody be so kind as to show me how?

For the first problem i got the solution set of$ (-\infty , -\frac{3}{2}) \bigcup (-\frac{1}{4}, 0 ) \bigcup (\frac{1}{2} , +\infty)$.

Does this look correct?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? We can't do all the work for you.

Comment: Are you asking for values of $x$ that satisfy both inequalities simultaneously, or are you asking two separate questions? And your second inequality doesn't make much sense: should that be $\frac{{{x^2} + 6x - 4}}{{x + 1}}$ (it looks like you are missing a linear term in the numerator)?

Comment: I'm asking two separate questions. And yes it should look like what you said. Sorry Rory and Lucas.

Comment: I am getting $x \geq 1/4$ and $x \leq -1/2$

Comment: For the second one I am getting, $x > -4 $ and $ x < 10$

Comment: @Francis, If you write down your steps here, others will tell you where you have made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

No, your answer to the first problem is not correct. You can check it easily with a graphing program or graphing calculator. A popular, free online grapher is [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), though I use the free programs [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/) and [Graph](http://www.padowan.dk/) and the non-free [TI-Nspire CX Teacher Software](http://education.ti.com/en/us/products/computer_software/ti-nspire-software/ti-nspire-and-ti-nspire-cas-teacher-software/tabs/overview).

The first problem twice uses the fact that $\left| y \right| \geqslant b$ (where $b$ is nonnegative) is equivalent to $y \leqslant  - b{\text{ or }}b \leqslant y$, and also uses the fact that $\left| y \right| \leqslant b$ is equivalent to $ - b \leqslant y \leqslant b$. Try that then get back to us with more details if you cannot succeed.

**ADDED:**

I should add another way to solve this. From the expression you can see that the left-hand side of the first problem has a graph that is a line with some "kinks" in it: in other words, a piecewise graph of connected lines. You could find where the kinks are, then investigate between the kinks, where the graph is a simple line.

The kinks occur where an absolute value is zero. So solve $x+1=0$, $3x-(x+1)=0$, and $3x+(x+1)=0$, remove any extraneous solution, and check the four (or less) lines for where the left hand side equals 2. I found this way to be easier than my first way, even though it sounds more complicated.